# Get current product id inside a function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom plugin to generate pdf of my products. I am calling this function inside the plugin to get all the gallery images of a product.

```
 function print_gallery_pdf(){
    $product_id = 33910;
    $gallery_image;
    $link = array();
    $get_product = new WC_Product($product_id);
    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
    foreach ($attachment_ids as $attachment_id){
        $gallery_image = wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, medium);
        array_push($link, $gallery_image);
    }
    return $link;
}
```

This function works perfectly when the id of the product is fixed, but whenever I try to get the ID dynamically is stops working. My dynamic function is:

```
function print_gallery_pdf(){
    global $product;
    $gallery_image;
    $link = array();
    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
    foreach ($attachment_ids as $attachment_id){
        $gallery_image = wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, medium);
        array_push($link, $gallery_image);
    }
    return $link;
}
```

It should work because I have seen people using this function but it doesn't work for me and I am unable to identify the issue.

Comment: I tried declaring the global $product outside my function in functions.php and I have received this error, **Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_id() on null**

Comment: Please ad the full code.

Comment: @Bhautik I have updated my functions in the question

Comment: From where you calling `print_gallery_pdf()` this function? please add that code as well. also from which page does this function call?

Comment: @Bhautik I have a custom plugin to generate the pdf of my products. I am calling this function on the product page, inside my plugin just to get the array of gallery images of a product. I think the problem is when we are calling this function, the product object is not properly loaded and that is why it returns this error **Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_id() on null **

Comment: Here is my code for the plugin where my function is being called [link](https://codeshare.io/eVNy47)

Comment: What is $data contain? do you have the product id inside that array?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was on a trip. To answer your question, No it doesn't have the product id

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you pass the ID as an argument for the function?

Comment: I have also tried declaring global product in the plugin and getting it id by `$product->get_id()` and passing it as an argument to my  function but that also doesn't work